# How to store laravel passport tokens in redis/memcache?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-passport

I have **SPA app** (Laravel + vue.js) with **laravel passport**.
A token is attached **to each request** and it is checked whether there is such a token in the database. Therefore, for each get / post request, there are one more request to check valid of token, which **every time sended to the database**. Ex. of request:

```
select * from `oauth_access_tokens` where `id` = '6756c7ef9221d9b897c1980a84349618aefce2e44db6380756b839a19c54bc5a0a65be3cd2a6ac90' limit 1
```

Can I **keep this table in redis**? In laravel passport **first check** if there is a **token in redis**, if not, **then check in the database**, and then **add it to redis**. I would like to **reduce the load** on the database in this way.

Answer (score -3):

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens',
    ],

    'Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\PruneOldTokens',
    ],
];
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: How it's going to overcome the issue?